# Using ! for Regex Number Validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to display an error message when the user enters anything other than a number using jQuery and regex. How do I do this?

```
if( $(this).val().match(/^[0-9]$/) ){
    alert("Wrong input. Only numbers allowed");
}
```

I tried using `!` but it did not work and I got no error message

```
if( $(this).val().match(/![0-9]/) ){
    alert("Wrong input. Only numbers allowed");
}
```

Comment: I think you're wanting to do `/[^0-9]/`, but your question isn't very clear.

Comment: Do you want to allow dots ? minus sign ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do it like this :

```
if( /\D/.test($(this).val()) ){
    alert("Wrong input. Only numbers allowed");
}
```

`\D` is any character that isn't a digit (`\d` is a digit).

Don't use [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) when you want to test if a string matches a pattern: it builds an useless array. What you need is [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

Now, let's imagine you want to test if the user entered a number, not just a sequence of digits. A number can be written with a sign, an exponent, a dot, etc. The proper way to test for that isn't to use a regex:

```
var s = $(this).val();
if (s != +s) {
    alert("Wrong input. Only numbers allowed");
}
```

`+s` is the conversion of `s` to a number, `NaN` if it isn't possible.

Comment: It isn't every day that you come across a good reason to use JavaScript's automatic type conversion in comparisons - nice!

Answer (score 4):

Negate the range, not the regex itself:

```
if( $(this).val().match(/[^0-9]/) ){
    alert("Wrong input. Only numbers allowed");
}
```

That will match any string containing non-numbers.

Answer (score 1):

To deal with both integer and floating point numbers..

```
if( !/^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/.test($(this).val()) ){
    alert("Wrong input. Only numbers allowed");
}
```

Comment: What about "-3" ? Or "2e-5" ? I know you can fix your regex, at least for those cases, but this is more complex than necessary.